# Create Consecutive Months

Tags: sql, oracle-12c

I am trying to create a database where each clients runs are summarized based on consecutive monthly runs.  The code below builds a table which looks like this:

[image]

```
drop table RUNNING_LOG;
create table running_log ( 
  run_date          date not null,  
  time_in_seconds   int  not null, 
  distance_in_miles int  not null,
  SERV_YRMO         VARCHAR2(6)
)

begin  
  insert into running_log values (date'2018-01-01', 420, 1,'201801');  
  insert into running_log values (date'2018-01-02', 2400, 5,'201801');  
  insert into running_log values (date'2018-01-03', 2430, 5,'201801');  
  insert into running_log values (date'2018-01-06', 2350, 5,'201801');  
  insert into running_log values (date'2018-02-07', 410, 1,'201802');  
  insert into running_log values (date'2018-02-10', 400, 1,'201802');  
  insert into running_log values (date'2018-02-13', 2300, 5,'201802');  
  insert into running_log values (date'2018-03-14', 425, 1,'201803');  
  insert into running_log values (date'2018-03-15', 422, 1,'201803');  
  commit;  
end;

select * from running_log
```

I would like the the final result to be:

[image]

In what way can I take consecutive months, break them into a single row where there is a break and group over multiple clients?

```
with grps as (  
  select run_date
        , row_number() over (order by run_date) rn ,  
         run_date - row_number() over (order by run_date) grp_date  
  from   running_log  
)  
  select min(run_date) first_run, max(run_date) last_run,   
         count(*) runs,   
         row_number() over (order by min(run_date)) grp  
  from   grps  
  group  by grp_date  
  order  by min(run_date)
```

Comment: `GROUP BY TRUNC(run_date, 'MONTH')`

Comment: I need a consecutive row of month x to month y

Comment: Please show desured answer strongly for source data which you have posted, not abstract "it must look like". You want to set a border between groups in a month in which there is no records, and month count in each group may differ - is it?

Comment: Think about: in CTE we generate year-month list. Then we calculate a field `isempty` which is 0 if at least 1 record in this year-month exists, and 1 otherwise. Then we calculate `SUM(isempty) OVER (ORDER BY yearmonth ASC)` - it will be group number...

Comment: I'd like yo have a grouping of anyset  of consecutive months not just a single month or even year but whenever there is a break to start a new row for a client

Comment: Could you post total code? I dont get it. I laid out exactly my desired outcome, where year or month is irrelevant just want min and max in row where gap doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

> Could you post total code?

Yes.

I publish detailed code, step by step. If you have a desire, you can reduce it by combining some individual steps.

```sql
WITH 
-- calculating data period borders
cte1 (mindate, maxdate) 
     AS ( SELECT ROUND(MIN(run_date), 'MONTH'),
                 ROUND(MAX(run_date), 'MONTH')
          FROM running_log ),
-- generating months list
cte2 (run_month) 
     AS (    SELECT mindate
             FROM cte1
         UNION ALL
             SELECT ADD_MONTHS(cte2.run_month, 1)
             FROM cte1, cte2 
             WHERE cte2.run_month < cte1.maxdate ),
-- marking empty months
cte3 (run_month, isempty)
     AS ( SELECT cte2.run_month, CASE WHEN 0 = COUNT(running_log.run_date) 
                                      THEN 1
                                      ELSE 0 END
          FROM cte2
          LEFT JOIN running_log 
              ON ROUND(running_log.run_date, 'MONTH') = cte2.run_month
          GROUP BY cte2.run_month ),
-- calculating group numbers for months
cte4 (run_month, group_num)
     AS ( SELECT run_month, SUM(isempty) OVER (ORDER BY run_month ASC)
          FROM cte3 ),
-- assigning group numbers to separate records
cte5 (run_date, time_in_seconds, distance_in_miles, SERV_YRMO, group_num)
     AS ( SELECT running_log.run_date, running_log.time_in_seconds, running_log.distance_in_miles, running_log.SERV_YRMO, cte4.group_num
          FROM cte4
          LEFT JOIN running_log 
              ON ROUND(running_log.run_date, 'MONTH') = cte4.run_month )
-- obtaining desured output
SELECT MIN(SERV_YRMO) "Min", MAX(SERV_YRMO) "Max", SUM(distance_in_miles) Runs, SUM(time_in_seconds) Seconds
FROM cte5
GROUP BY group_num
ORDER BY group_num
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=27a8b754afd23b052ef08a8869b5664e)